# Is it possible to get a stereo audio feed into Chrome?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

For instance, if I have a stereo audio interface/sound card, could I get the left and right channels separately into javascript for realtime-ish audio processing of stereo audio?

Comment: I originally asked this question because I was thinking of doing stereo audio processing in javascript in a raspberry pi using chromium.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's actually not possible to get stereo audio into Chrome. According to the following URL: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=453876

> Unfortunately we don't support [...] multiple devices at the moment.